# La suma no coincide ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>    

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int n, suma, cal;


    cout << "# veces "; cin >> n;


    for (int i = 1; i <=  n; i++) {
         cal =  2 * 2;

         if( i % 2 == 0){
            cal *= -1;
         }
         else {

            cal *= 1;
        }
        suma += cal;
    }

    cout << "\n" << suma;


    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿ Y que es exactamente lo que quieres que te de ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, tienes un error acá:

```
suma += cal;
```

Porque suma no tiene un valor, es como si apuntara a la nada y le estás sumando 4, y como que, no se sabe el resultado en sí porque dependerá del lugar de la memoria que esté ocupando y cómo saber cuál es el valor de ese lugar?

Tienes que hacer, en la declaración, `suma=0`; porque sino, no tiene sentido que realices la suma.

Y el algoritmo en sí, qué es lo que quieres que haga? Porque tal y como está ahí, lo que hace es, si n es par sum=0 (en el caso de que hayas declarado sum=0 antes, sino no tiene sentido tu algoritmo) y en el caso de que sea impar, valdrá 4.

Si n es igual a 3, entonces:

> Cuando i = 1, cal = 4, sum = 0 + 4 = 4
>
> Cuando i = 2, cal = -4, sum = 4 - 4 = 0
>
> Cuando i = 3, cal = 4, sum = 0 + 4 = 4

Si en cambio n = 4, entonces, sum cuando i = 4, será 4 - 4 = 0

Y así para cualquier n no importa que sea enormemente grande.

Espero te sirva para lograr lo que quieres!

Answer (score 0):

No dices cuál es el error que te da, pero supongo que será al mostrarse en pantalla la variable suma. Seguramente, en pantalla se te mostrará un valor no deseado que está guardado en esa variable. Se debe a que no la has inicializado con un valor por defecto, en este caso, te recomiendo que sea suma = 0;

Cuando no le das un valor a una variable, ésta cogerá el valor del espacio de memoria en la que esté almacenada la variable. Esto puede suponer un correcto funcionamiento del programa, pero con una muestra de valor en pantalla errónea.

Espero que te haya servido y un saludo.